# how to integrate whole html template in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I also done a single webpage into the codeigniter.

But performing "href" it doesn't works.

Give a solution for how to include whole site into the codeigniter.

I think may be i need to create controller(into the directory) files for each and every view(into the directory) files.

Note : My whole templates are in the "view/pages" folder.

i already created "pages.php" in controller folder.

After changing route.php it only works on index.php. not for all other pages when perform links from index page.

My **pages.php** code is below

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    function view()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('pages/index');
        //$this->load->view('pages/login');

        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand you. Do you mean something like this?

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('pages/index');
        //$this->load->view('pages/login');

        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }
    function aboutUs()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
        $this->load->view('pages/aboutUs');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
    }
}
?>
```

In this way you reach your index page through www.yourserver.ext/pages/ (or www.yourserver.ext/pages/index) and, for example, your about us page through www.yourserver.ext/pages/aboutUs

Also you can set a param and load the page depending on it

Comment: Yes. exactly i want this. it's works good in index.php. but doesn't works in aboutus.php. My changed route.php file is $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';

Comment: the default controller is pages, not pages/index